# SVG dominant baseline and small coordinate systems

Tags: css, svg

I'm using a coordinate system for SVG that is very small.  The whole screen might be as small as 10x10 units.

Normally, this isn't a problem, provided I scale everything correctly.  However, I'm having an issue vertically centering some text.  Take this SVG for example:

```css
svg {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
}

svg text {
  font-size: 0.2px;
}

rect {
  fill: #4f4;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" width="1" height="1" x="1" y="5">
  <rect width="1" height="1"></rect>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Text!</text>
</svg>
```

The text appears totally outside of the box:

[image: Broken SVG]

However, if I remove the `middle` value from the `dominant-baseline` attribute, the text appears back in the box:

[image: Mostly correct SVG]

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/uk40x3v6/

What I think is happening is that there is some other measurement I'm not accounting for that is hard set in pixel land, and since `1` could be hundreds of pixels and not 1 pixel, I think this is throwing things off.

Is that the case?  And if so, is there anything I can do to get that text centered vertically?

**Edit:** Strangely, I can't reproduce this problem anywhere but my laptop.  Chrome v78 on Windows 10 x64.  (Screenshot tests:  https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/i81ab6009f75bfdb/screenshots/z3e7e4c7478d4e08b824)  Even with that exact browser and OS, the problem occurs on my machine but not others.  It's not a caching issue.  Perhaps a browser rendering flag or something?  What all does Chrome rely upon to render SVG?  Anything weird or special?

Comment: Use a larger viewBox and scale up your numbers

Comment: Read about the [The Limits of Numbers in SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html) Also check the [browser compatibility for `dominant-baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: Just to clarify, this `1x1` viewbox is used within the context of an outer viewbox that is larger, say `10x10` or `20x20`.  (Not "large", but larger than `1x1`.)  @RobertLongson I'll scale up if I have to, but I'd rather avoid it if possible.  This coordinate system is very convenient and has so far worked for everything, even the text, except for the `dominant-baseline`.

Comment: @enxaneta `dominant-baseline` has been around basically forever, is well supported, and is definitely supported in my browser.  As for numerical limits, I'm not exceeding them, even by the extreme use case example mentioned in the blog.  I suspect that there is some other measurement that is based on pixel sizes rather than font size, for which I need to adjust to get it back into scale.

Comment: Running both the snippet and the fiddle do not render at all like what you describe on any of my browsers on macOs. First the svg is rendered as 4*4px (20em @ 0.2px -> 4px), and the text is correctly in the center, even when changing the font-size (though it will be bigger than the svg element quite soon).

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting.  I'm using Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Interesting indeed. Same "correct" result on all the browsers on my andro-phone and on a non-retina macOs... We agrre just clicking the run button should be enough?

Comment: @Kaiido Yes!  Very strange.  I just did a cross-browser test and no other browser looks like mine... including the same version of Chrome.  I revised the test, breaking out `font-size` from the `svg` selector since it was affecting the width/height:  https://fiddle.jshell.net/uk40x3v6/show/  Boxes are the right size, but the second box's text is well outside of the box.  However, when I test across 18 different browsers, it's fine!  I'm re-re-re-checking my test and assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a Chrome bug.  I'm not sure which update fixed it, but it started working along the way.

All is well now in Chrome v84.